# Can't integrate a Create-react-app project

Tags: javascript, git, create-react-app

I'm trying to integrate that https://github.com/ZACHSTRIVES/Draw-Guess-Game in a create-react-app project that run well.

My consol give me back this information. Can any one help??

You can see the project: http://51.75.12.53:3000/login

```
[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
index.js:1 Warning: React does not recognize the `computedMatch` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `computedmatch` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.
    at div
    at Switch (http://51.75.12.53:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:257310:29)
    at Router (http://51.75.12.53:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:256743:30)
    at BrowserRouter (http://51.75.12.53:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:256363:35)
    at App (http://51.75.12.53:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:476:80)
console.<computed> @ index.js:1
webpackHotDevClient.js:138 src/components/canvas.js
  Line 65:6:   React Hook React.useEffect has a missing dependency: 'socket'. Either include it or remove the dependency array                                               react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  Line 73:6:   React Hook React.useEffect has missing dependencies: 'getRandomWords', 'socket', 'userName', and 'words'. Either include them or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  Line 82:6:   React Hook React.useEffect has a missing dependency: 'socket'. Either include it or remove the dependency array                                               react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  Line 89:6:   React Hook React.useEffect has a missing dependency: 'stopDrawing'. Either include it or remove the dependency array                                          react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  Line 224:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'debouncedHandleResize'. Either include it or remove the dependency array                                      react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

src/components/finalLeaderBoardMask.js
  Line 16:6:   React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'players'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  Line 87:12:  'handleRestartGame' is defined but never used                                                               no-unused-vars

src/components/game.js
  Line 20:6:  React Hook React.useEffect has missing dependencies: 'id', 'socket', and 'userName'. Either include them or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  Line 28:6:  React Hook React.useEffect has a missing dependency: 'socket'. Either include it or remove the dependency array                          react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  Line 42:6:  React Hook React.useEffect has a missing dependency: 'socket'. Either include it or remove the dependency array                          react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

src/components/gameRoom.js
  Line 28:6:  React Hook React.useEffect has a missing dependency: 'socket'. Either include it or remove the dependency array                                       react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  Line 34:6:  React Hook React.useEffect has a missing dependency: 'socket'. Either include it or remove the dependency array                                       react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  Line 43:6:  React Hook React.useEffect has missing dependencies: 'roomInfo.roomID', 'socket', and 'userName'. Either include them or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  Line 52:6:  React Hook React.useEffect has missing dependencies: 'roomInfo.roomID', 'socket', and 'userName'. Either include them or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  Line 62:6:  React Hook React.useEffect has missing dependencies: 'socket', 'success', and 'userName'. Either include them or remove the dependency array          react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

src/components/leaderBoardMask.js
  Line 15:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'players'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

src/components/lobby/lobby.js
  Line 30:10:  'loading' is assigned a value but never used                                                                                                  no-unused-vars
  Line 38:6:   React Hook React.useEffect has missing dependencies: 'history' and 'socket'. Either include them or remove the dependency array               react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  Line 46:6:   React Hook React.useEffect has a missing dependency: 'socket'. Either include it or remove the dependency array                               react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  Line 60:6:   React Hook React.useEffect has missing dependencies: 'history' and 'socket'. Either include them or remove the dependency array               react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  Line 68:6:   React Hook React.useEffect has missing dependencies: 'socket' and 'userName'. Either include them or remove the dependency array              react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
 
  Line 15:6:  React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'socket' and 'time'. Either include them or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
printWarnings @ webpackHotDevClient.js:138
howler.js:2500 The AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resumed (or created) after a user gesture on the page.
setupAudioContext @ howler.js:2500
howler.js:2500 The AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resumed (or created) after a user gesture on the page. 
setupAudioContext @ howler.js:2500
localhost:8000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NwmEcfH:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix missing dependency warning when using useEffect React Hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840294/how-to-fix-missing-dependency-warning-when-using-useeffect-react-hook)

Comment: None of these messages come from Git itself. They are probably all from some hook you have installed.